# I changed my PATH and now for every command it returns "command not found"

Tags: path, command

I am on MacOSX, using the iTerm and I'm very new at all of this. I am trying to prepare for installing bioinformatics programs, so I made new directories for "Scripts" and "Programs" and wanted to add them to the PATH.

This is what I did:

```
nano .bash_profile
export PATH= "$PATH:$HOME/Scripts"
PATH= "$PATH:$HOME/Programs"
source .bash_profile
```

it returned:

```
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/Tori/Scripts': not a valid identifier
```

I tried re-entering the profile using nano and it said `-bash: nano: command not found` so I closed out that window, reopened a new session, and it came up with the same "not a valid identifier" message and now won't recognize any commands.

What did I mess up and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can't have spaces between the `PATH=` and the `"$PATH:..."`

Answer (score 3):

This will fix the issue:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/Tori/Scripts
```

The root cause was the extra space after the `=`.

Obviously, you'll need to edit your `.bash_profile` afterwards and remove these extra spaces.

Comment: That will fix the issue short-term. The Asker will still need to edit `.bash_profile` and remove the space after the `PATH=`. (I know you know this, but the Asker might not.)

Answer (score 0):

Not having a Mac here, try calling `/usr/bin/nano` or `/bin/nano` instead of plain `nano`. As you probably know, all directories in your `PATH` are searched for binaries, and having managed to garble it, it will not find your `nano` unless you tell it where exactly to look.

As remarked by @jasonwryan, those spaces after the `=` look very suspicious, those probably shouldn't be there.

(For future reference, since changes in your profile only become active in new windows, it's a good idea to try if everything works in a new terminal window, leaving the old one open.)